# Consume .Net AuthenticationService with jQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication

I have enabled the WCF AuthenticationService in my web application, following the instructions I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398990.aspx). Now I need to know how to use the service, but I would like to do it using only jQuery and AJAX, without having to add a ScriptManager. So far none of the examples I have seen actually demonstrate how to do this; all they show is how to create the client classes and call the service from your code-behind, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok, I may be on to something here:

function IsLoggedIn() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Services/AuthSvc.svc/IsLoggedIn",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        error: function () { },
        success: function (result) { alert(result) }
    });
}
The alert is popping up, but the problem is that the result object is always null. But maybe that's just because the service isn't actually getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have given up on this idea. I am just going to add a Service Reference, and log in from my code-behind.